# Java compile error, why doesn't it work?

Tags: java

**So this is my code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Metoder {

    static void skrivHilsen(){
    System.out.println("Hei, "+ navn +"! Du er fra "+ bosted +"." );
}

public static void main (String[]args){
    Scanner in;
    String navn;
    String bosted;

    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt navn:");
    navn = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt bosted:");
    bosted = in.nextLine();
    skrivHilsen();

    System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt navn:");
    navn = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt bosted:");
    bosted = in.nextLine();
    skrivHilsen();

    System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt navn:");
    navn = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt bosted:");
    bosted = in.nextLine();
    skrivHilsen();
    }
}
```

**and when I try to compile it, I get this error:**

```
Metoder.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("Hei, "+ navn +"! Du er fra "+ bosted +"." );
                            ^
symbol:   variable navn
location: class Metoder
```

-

```
Metoder.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("Hei, "+ navn +"! Du er fra "+ bosted +"." );
                                                  ^
symbol:   variable bosted
location: class Metoder

2 errors
```

Comment: Please give more details. What do you want to do, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields **navn** and **bosted** are defined in the `main` `method` and you try to access them from `skrivHilsen method`. That is not possible.

If you have only `static methods` then you have to define those fields as `class` level variables or pass them as arguments into `skrivHilsen` method.

So it would look like this:

```
static void skrivHilsen(String navn, String bosted){
    System.out.println("Hei, "+ navn +"! Du er fra "+ bosted +"." );
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //...
    skrivHilsen(navn, bosted);
}
```

Yet this is still not the best solution, because you're running all your code in `static main method`. You should try to make your object work work for you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//creating a class
public class Metoder {
    //defining instance fields. Those will be visible/accesible from all instance(not static) methods.
    private Scanner userInput;
    private String navn;
    private String bosted;

    //constructor - used to create an object of your Metoder class
    private Metoder(final Scanner userInput) {
        this.userInput = userInput;
    }

    //here do as little as possible. Initialize userInput, and create the object.
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        new Metoder(in).run();  //creating new object and running it(method name can be different).
    }

    //here you all your important stuff.
    private void run() {
        System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt navn:");
        navn = userInput.nextLine();  //navn is visible/accessible here as it is defined as instance field.
        System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt bosted:");
        bosted = userInput.nextLine();
        skrivHilsen();

        System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt navn:");
        navn = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt bosted:");
        bosted = userInput.nextLine();
        skrivHilsen();

        System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt navn:");
        navn = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt bosted:");
        bosted = userInput.nextLine();
        skrivHilsen();
    }

    //navn/bosted are visible/accessible here as they are defined as instance fields.
    private void skrivHilsen() {
        System.out.println("Hei, "+ navn +"! Du er fra "+ bosted +"." );
    }
}
```

Moreover you could move this block:

```
System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt navn:");
navn = userInput.nextLine();
System.out.println("Skriv inn ditt bosted:");
bosted = userInput.nextLine();
```

to another method so that it is writen only once and not tree times. Then you can only invoke the method three times(or more if you need). You can use a loop for that.

Answer (score 3):

`String navn;` is a *method local* variable in `main()` method. you are trying to use it in `skrivHilsen()`.

Answer (score 0):

Define class level static variables which you require

```
static String navn;
static String bosted;
```

Currently, the variables are defined in the scope of `main()`, which the other static method cannot read.

Answer (score 0):

**navn** and **bosted** aren't defined in the methode `skrivHilsen()`

```
public class Metoder {


    static String navn;
    static String bosted;

    static void skrivHilsen(){
        System.out.println("Hei, "+ navn +"! Du er fra "+ bosted +"." );
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
static void skrivHilsen(String navn, String bosted) {
    System.out.println("Hei, "+ navn +"! Du er fra "+ bosted +"." );
}
```

and call it like this:

```
skrivHilsen(navn, bosted);
```

Because you initialized them as local variables in the method, rather than field variables. You can send them over as parameters, though.